# How to remove duplicate records in SQL table based on certain conditions and multi-criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, duplicates, ranking-functions

The following table consists of the columns EmployeeID, JobNum, CompDate.
Basically there are 3 different employees that have certain job ids and their completed date time associated with them. There are some jobNum that have no association to a particular EmployeeID and may have a complete date.

Problem: 
1) Remove the records for a EmployeeID when the Complete date is not null or is populated with date.

2) Delete the record that has null values for both columns JobNum and CompDate for an Employee WHEN there is a record for that EmployeeID that consists of an open job (when JobNum is NOT NULL and CompDate is NULL).  THIS IS FOR DUPLICATES.

Tried using ranking function with case statements. Does not rank properly.

```
       [JobNum],       
       [CompDate], 
       RANK ( ) OVER( PARTITION BY [EmployeeID] ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN ([JobNum] is null AND [CompDate] is null) THEN 1 
         WHEN ([JobNum] is not null AND [CompDate] is null) THEN 2
         WHEN ([JobNum] is not null AND [CompDate] is not null) THEN 3 
            END ASC) as Rank
  FROM [dbo].test1
  WHERE [EmployeeID] IN (SELECT [EmployeeID] FROM dbo.test1
            GROUP BY [EmployeeID]
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

```
EmployeeID    JobNum          CompDate                    Rank
   1             NULL            NULL                      1
   1             401             NULL                      2
   1             435             NULL                      2
   1             358       2019-07-15 15:10:57.810         4
   2             285             NULL                      1
   2             299       2019-07-15 15:14:04.603         2
   2             305       2019-07-14 15:10:57.810         2
   2             330       2019-06-13 10:10:30.710         2
   3             NULL           NULL                       1
   3             435            NULL                       2
   3             402       2019-07-11 13:10:47.610         3
```

```
Ex:    

                EmployeeID    JobNum          CompDate                    Rank
Delete this ->       1           NULL            NULL                      1
when this exists ->  1           401             NULL                      2
when this exists ->  1           435             NULL                      2
                     1           358       2019-07-15 15:10:57.810         4
```

Comment: Condition (2) is really hard to process and your data doesn't seem to have any duplicates.  Can you provide clarity?

Comment: Hey Gordon, so there's multiple Jobs tied to one EmployeeID. I want to be able to delete record that has null values for both JobNum and CompDate for that specific EmployeeID whenever  there exists a record that has JobNum as not null but CompDate is null.                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                
Example:

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want only rows where `compdate` is null and one of the following two conditions:

- `jobnum` is null
- `jobnum` is not null and no rows for the employee have `jobnum` as null

I'm not sure what `rank()` has to do with these filtering conditions:

```
select t.*
from test1 t
where t.compdate is not null and  -- condition 1
      (t.jobnum is null or
       not exists (select 1
                   from test1 tt
                   where tt.employeeid = t.employeeid and 
                         tt.compdate is null and
                         tt.jobnum is null
                  )
      );
```

Comment: I was going to use the rank function to rank them per EmployeeID and delete records which is to be used in the stored procedure. I ll give this a try. Thanks!